# DialogSheets("Name").Labels.Visible = True not working on all DialogSheets in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been given an ancient but, for the most part, working Excel solution.
It uses a lot of DialogSheets (an Excel 5/95 technique before UserForms).

Now I'm trying to figure out what the author tried to do, the code is pretty horrible. One problem I stumbled across is this:

Some sheets work fine with code like:

```
DialogSheets("Name1").Show
DialogSheets("Name1").Labels.Visible = True
DialogSheets("Name1").EditBoxes.Visible = True
DialogSheets("Name1").CheckBoxes.Visible = True
DialogSheets("Name1").DropDowns.Visible = True
```

On others, I get a:

> runtime error 1004 "Unable to set the Visible property of the Labels class"

I cannot quite work out the difference, and the documentation on Dialogsheets is pretty sparse. If anyone had any idea I'd appreciate a suggestion.

## Update

The answers suggest that some DialogSheets may not have Labels, thus throwing the 1004. This is not the case. This happens in the ImmediateWindow:

```
?DialogSheets("Name1").Labels.Count
205 
?DialogSheets("Name2").Labels.Count
7 
DialogSheets("Name1").Labels.Visible = True ' Throws 1004
DialogSheets("Name2").Labels.Visible = True ' executes fine
?DialogSheets("Name2").Labels.Visible = True ' returns true
True
```

Answer (score 1):

The code above sets the visibility of the Labels, DropDowns, EditBoxes and CheckBoxes to `True`.

It throws **error 1004**, because on some `DialogSheets` the Labels, DropDowns, EditBoxes or CheckBoxes are missing. And it works on those, where all 4 are present.

---

To see it working, close all Excel applications. Then open a brand new one and run this code:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim someDialogSheet As DialogSheet
    Set someDialogSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(Type:=xlDialogSheet)

    With someDialogSheet
        .Name = "SoReadyToHelp"
        .Labels.Add(5, 5, 5, 5).Select
        .DropDowns.Add(10, 10, 10, 10).Select
        .CheckBoxes.Add(15, 15, 15, 15).Select
        Debug.Print .Labels.Visible
        Debug.Print .CheckBoxes.Visible
        Debug.Print .DropDowns.Visible
        .Show
    End With

End Sub
```

---

Or there is `On Error Resume Next` somewhere on the code where it works.

Comment: Like on the comment for the answer below; the .Labels.Count is 205, yet .Labels.Visible still throws a 1004 run-time error.

Comment: ImmediateWindow in VBA:
`?DialogSheets("Name1").Labels.Count
 205 
 ?DialogSheets("Name2").Labels.Count
 7 
DialogSheets("Name1").Labels.Visible = True ' throws 1004
DialogSheets("Name2").Labels.Visible = True ' executes fine`

Comment: @ExternalUse - strange. Still, if you try the code above on a new workbook, would it work? In general, check for some read-only property of these labels.

Comment: I shall try that and look through the labels' individual visibility state.

Answer (score 0):

The code will fail if there are no labels to make visible.
Add a check like this, to make sure there are any before making them visible:

```
If DialogSheets("Name1").Labels.Count > 0 Then
    DialogSheets("Name1").Labels.Visible = True
End If
```

**Edit after comment**
Then I suggest you try something like this:

```
For Each lbl In DialogSheets("Name1").Labels
    lbl.Visible = True
Next
```

Comment: DialogSheets("Name1").Labels.Count = 205 -  that can't be the solution

Comment: @ExternalUse I've added another approach now.

Comment: I've done this before, but I wasn't certain that this is what the original author had in mind. I thought that applying the visible property to the labels class (ie the collection of labels) may have some difference to looping through the collection; which is why I was trying to figure out what the difference in those failing or non-failing Dialogsheets was. Thanks anyhow!